# How to move patterns in a string in r?

Tags: r, string, data-manipulation, stringr

I am trying to code a function that would allow me to move certain patterns in a string in r. For example, if my strings are pattern_string1, pattern_string2, pattern_string3, pattern_string4, I want to mutate them to string1_pattern, string2_pattern, string3_pattern, string4_pattern.

In oder to achieve this, I tried the following:

```
string_flip <- function(x, pattern){
  if(str_detect(x, pattern)==TRUE){
    str_remove(x, pattern) %>%
    paste(x, "pattern", sep = "_")
  }
}
```

However, when I try to apply this onto a vector of strings by the following code:

```
stringvector <- c(pattern_string1, pattern_string2, pattern_string3, pattern_string4, string5, string6)
string_flip(stringvector, "pattern")
```

it returns a warning and changes all vectors, not only the vectors that contain "pattern". In addition it does not only add pattern to the end of the string, it doubles the string itself as well, so I get the following result:

```
[1] "_string1_pattern_string1_pattern" "_string2_pattern_string2_pattern" "_string3_pattern_string3_pattern"
[4] "_string4_pattern_string4_pattern" "string5_string5_pattern"                "string6_string6_pattern"
```

Can anybody help me with this?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your function `string_flip` is not vectorised. It works for only one string at a time.
2. I think you have additional `x` which is why the string is doubling.
3. In `paste`, `pattern` should not be in quotes.

Try this function.

```
library(stringr)


string_flip <- function(x, pattern){
  trimws(ifelse(str_detect(x, pattern), 
     str_remove(x, pattern) %>% paste(pattern, sep = "_"), x), whitespace = '_')
}


stringvector <- c('pattern_string1', 'pattern_string2', 'pattern_string3', 'pattern_string4')
string_flip(stringvector, "pattern")

#[1] "string1_pattern" "string2_pattern" "string3_pattern" "string4_pattern"
```